# Работа Selenium WebDriver в C++

Tags: c++, selenium-webdriver

Есть ли возможность работать с Selenium WebDriver в C++? Если да, то как установить данное чудо ни где информацию не могу найти. Если же нет возможности работать с Selenium WebDriver в С++, то может аналоги есть какие нибудь? 
P.S. За ответы благодарю заранее.

Answer (score 5):

Возможность есть. Используя selenium server и JsonWireProtocol. В C++ можно реализовать CURL запросы к selenium server и сделать автоматизированные веб тесты на C++.

Для тех не хочет читать дальше, вот сразу ссылка: [Форк Webdriver++](https://github.com/durdyev/webdriverxx).

Есть несколько библиотек на C++ которые уже решают эту задачу.
Первый проект это Webdriver++ By sekogan но последний commit был 3 года назад, и кажется что код немного устарел и технологии ушли вперед, и не все работает на днный момент.

Поэтому я сделал форк Webdriver++, и исправил некоторые баги, а так же сделал этот проект как shared library, теперь есть возможность использовать эту библиотеку в любом вашем C++ проекте.

Пример кода форк Webdriver++.

```
#include <webdriverxx/webdriverxx.h>
using namespace webdriverxx;

int main() {
   WebDriver firefox = Start(Firefox());
   firefox
       .Navigate("http://google.com")
       .FindElement(ByClass("class_name"))
       .SendKeys("Hello, world!")
       .Submit();
   return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Селениума нет на С++, что подтверждает официальный сайт селениума http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/#client-drivers

И вряд ли есть аналоги. Этот язык не используется под подобные задачи, на сколько мне известно.

Советую использовать С# как замену под даный проэкт... Все таки одна семья языков с плюсами. И ИДЕ та же.