# Получить ссылку кнопки веб страницы средствами c++

Tags: c++

Каким образом можно получить ссылку от элемента (кнопки: Inspect in Game), например, данной страницы?
https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/M4A1-S%20%7C%20Decimator%20%28Field-Tested%29

[image: кнопка]

Comment: а с какой библиотекой планируете работать? Qt, curl,boost, чистые сокеты, winurl?

Comment: вообще в проекте отправляю http запросы, используя библиотеку cpprest, но ее функционала недостаточно насколько я понял, поэтому boost/curl

Comment: думаю, для того, что бы получить страницу, ее функционала достаточно. Эта часть у Вас получается?

Comment: если просто получить код страницы и распарсить, то не получиться вытащить оттуда ссылку
"link":"steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D7263895318874843724"
полная ссылка, нужная мне, получается после выполнения скриптов
если, я конечно, все правильно понимаю

Comment: возможно, ее нужно сложить с кусков.

Comment: в ссылке есть три ключа, A, M и D. в готовых ссылках все значения разные.
ни одно из полученных значений любого ключа не подставляется просто так.
получается, мне нужно эмулировать выполнение скриптов на странице.
нашел такой же вопрос, но там автор пишет на питоне
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722523/get-inspect-link-from-item-on-steam-community-market
там в решении выполняется скрипт, после уже достается значение из тега

Comment: да, там пошли по простому пути - использовали selenium (грубо говоря браузер) и проблема решается проще.

Comment: подскажете? пример был бы большим плюсом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611767/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-selenium-webdriver-%D0%B2-c